# LWC - registerTestWireAdapter for lightning/navigation with imperative call from wired fails

Tags: pagereference, lwc-jest

Let's say we have

```
@wire (CurrentPageReference)
getStateParameters(pageRef) {
    if (pageRef) {
        /// some statements here
        this.setSomeData();
    }
}
 setSomeData() {
    getCardData({ 
        language : this.userLanguage
    }).then(response => {
        this.section = JSON.parse(response);
    }).catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    }) 
}
```

where `getCardData` is an imperative Apex call.
There is need to create jest tests but it fails with `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`.
i'm sure i've provided all necessary info via mocks.
in jest we have

```
CurrentPageReferenceAdapter.emit(pageRef);
```

and it fails on this statement

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error, I presume the issue is related to how you're mocking your apex call

If you're going to do the following based on imperative apex

```js
getCardData({ 
        language : this.userLanguage
    }).then(response => {
        ...
```

Then, in your test, you need to provide a [resolved promise](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockresolvedvaluevalue) (to go into `then`) or a [rejected value](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockrejectedvaluevalue) (to go into the `error`).

You can use the provided functions

- `.mockResolvedValue(yourMockData)`
- `.mockRejectedValue(yourMockData)`

But, if you look at what they're doing - you'll see, as an example with resolve, they're returning your value(mock data) within a resolved promise

```js
jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve(value));
```

Which is why it allows your code to then go into `.then(response =>`  successfully (or error in the rejected scenario).

You can see an example of this in [lwc-recipes](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes) under [apexImperativeMethodWithParams](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/main/force-app/main/default/lwc/apexImperativeMethodWithParams/apexImperativeMethodWithParams.js) & its corresponding [jest test](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/main/force-app/main/default/lwc/apexImperativeMethodWithParams/__tests__/apexImperativeMethodWithParams.test.js) as well.